# How to draw multiple polylines by clicking?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-polyline

I was looking for a solution but all are how to draw polylines from the json file etc. Main question is how to get the functionality to create a new polyline and store old in array each time when click on button "New Polyline"? Second how to leave polylines and draw new on map after click "New Polyline" button and clean and restore only when click right button? May better way is to store Polylines outside the class, or make a new separately class for this? May you have to approach this differently?

Bad demo but highlight what I mean I hope: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bartek/x8A7V/)

Array was moved to global scope but can't setMap on last polyline works only via clearOverlays function. Now complications arise on other buttons. I create additional global object newPoly but don't know whether is good idea may better get object from myPolyline? In other side restore case can't set on map stored in array polylines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the polylines you've made, create another global variable to store the polylines and push them in, and at the same time, setMap(null) on the last polyline in the array. You can't store the polylines you've made in the same object, since you're making a new one each time.
So move:

```
this.polyLines = [];
```

out of the class, and into the global scope, or into another class, its fine to leave the marker array in there, since that's local to that polyline instance.

this should also help - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#OverlaysOverview

Comment: Very helpful but I would like additional experts hints. Although it's old question, I don't close it yet.

Comment: I'll post a new jsfiddle example, just leave the question open-

Comment: Ok I still working on it and learn literally, some progress has been.

Comment: your latest version of the jsfiddle seems to work, now with the getPath.clear(), what else are you trying to accomplish

Comment: In case new don't work set map null: lastPoly.polyMarkers[i].setMap(null); I'll move it to clean case and I'll leave lines on map when draw new. Next issue is same type like first in restore case don't work: polyLines[i].setMap(map); Last, I have pull out newPoly object to global I don't know whether is it good practice. Maybe I should remove last object before creating new one?